# Xcode doesn't show options in build settings

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I developed a game with Unity and created the Xcode project, so now I want to publish the game to the App Store. I bought the license and set the correct key in the Mac, but there's a problem: I can't select options in the build settings; it show me only a blank text area. The first time I opened the project, I was able to change the configuration and Xcode showed me the options.

How i can fix this problem?

this is a screen:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  You say you cannot modify the build settings, but the screenshot shows that you are doing just that (in order to close that text area click into the main build settings window, within the left margin).

Comment: I can access to the build settings, but i can't se the option to change the settings. So for example if an option is YES or NO, i can only see the text area that show YES and not a combo box to choose NO. I can write it manually, but when i must choose the provisioning profile i can't type it manually because i don't know the exact worlds.

Comment: You rarely need to double-click an option and go to the text-edit area.  Most options provide a drop-down selection so if you are missing settings you want to change, please explain what they are.

Comment: I try to set signing identity and provisioning profile to archive my project, but i haven't the drop down selection. In all the build settings i haven't drop down selection, so maybe is an Xcode problem or i make something wrong ?

Comment: Certainly the latter, however it's not clear exactly what.

Comment: I tried in every way and I looked at a lot of tutorials , I just can not understand what has gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning to change provisioning profile and code signing identity?

It's under **Code Signing** section. Under that set the correct developer, publisher profiles and provisioning profile.

Comment: yes i'm planning to change provisioning profile and code signing identity but i can't do that, Xcode not show me the options, in Code Signing i have only "iPhone Developer" option and provisioning profile show me a blank text area, how i can see the options ?
screen: [screenshot](http://example.com) https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ojxmmfgf6sihxs/Schermata%202015-09-23%20alle%2009.05.42.png?dl=0

Comment: It's probably because you haven't added your developer account to xcode.  Got to Xcode->Preference-> Accounts and add your account. Then go back to the screen which you took the screenshot , and go to 'General' tab and select your 'Team' , if there's no team Xcode will ask to automatically fix it for you.

Comment: I also do this: [screen 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b7lwtlyc2vq7g3i/Schermata%202015-09-23%20alle%2009.17.12.png?dl=0) [screen 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvhig72bpt263ii/Schermata%202015-09-23%20alle%2009.17.27.png?dl=0) , but it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is you haven't created a valid provisioning profile for your app. Click 'Fix Issue' button.

Comment: Re: screen 2.  Did you try pressing "Fix Issue"?  If you do, Xcode will generate a Provisioning Profile that matches the capabilities you have chosen.  Managing PPs is tricky to say the least and causes me head aches.

Comment: @trojanfoe true. However I think he have to create a provisioning profile for app store distribution using apple member center. Xcode won't automatically create distribution provisioning profiles, I can't exactly remember though.

Comment: Yes i try to press "Fix Issue", but xcode tell me this error because i haven't an IOS device registered: screen  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gw2rka7g1e9ta16/Schermata%202015-09-23%20alle%2009.24.56.png?dl=0)

I think because Xcode request a developer provisioning profile that require a device while i need only a distribution provisioning profile

Comment: Yeah - if you want to submit to the app store you need to start with iTunes Connect and creating an app id etc.

Comment: I already create the distribution provisioning profiles in the apple member center and add it to xCode: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt2m9mkt79ygmq9/Schermata%202015-09-23%20alle%2009.29.20.png?dl=0) [link 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxpjdp8t9bf70ut/Schermata%202015-09-23%20alle%2009.29.42.png?dl=0)

Comment: I already create in iTunes Connect app id, ecc... i need only to archive and upload the app to iTunes connect

Comment: Have you linked it with correct App ID?  If so, did you change your bundle identifier after creating these profiles?